# enable CORS on Iris Couch

Tags: couchdb, cors

Following [instructions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-431?focusedCommentId=13033669&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13033669) to enable CORS for my [iriscouch](http://www.iriscouch.com/):

1. `/_config/httpd/cors` set to `true`
2. Add a section: `/_config/cors/my.iriscouch.com:6984` set to `"http://localhost http://myapp.com"`

Then test it:

```
$ curl -I https://my.iriscouch.com:6984/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B)
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2012 10:49:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 40
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

but **no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response**...

Also tried to restart the server:

```
$ curl -XPOST -HContent-Type:application/json https://me:XXXX@my.iriscouch.com:6984/_restart
{"ok":true}
```

But no more luck...

--

Does anyone successfuly enable CORS for his iriscouch ?

**NB: CORS patch is supposed to be already applied for my account.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I made it work using the following configuration:

```
section | option      | value
-------------------------------
cors    | credentials | true
cors    | origins     | *
httpd   | enable_cors | true
```

Additionally, if you are doing any ajax requests from your webapp, make sure you pass the    **withCredentials** parameter set to **true**.

Example for AngularJS:

```
$http({withCredentials: true, ...}).post(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you open the 'Configuration' tool, you will find '**enable_cors**' under '**httpd**'.  You want to change that value to '**true**'.

Next, if you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you will find an '**Add a new section**' link.  You want to click on that and add an '**origins**' option with the value of '*****' in the '**cors**' section.  You can set the '**origins**' value to an actual URL but this will enable CORS for everybody.

This is how I got it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is now possible. I've enabled CORS though I have not yet tested it. I'm just getting started playing with CouchDB.

Check configuration. CORS should show disabled.
http: //YOURDOMAIN.iriscouch.com/_utils/config.html

See instructions here to install add-cors-to-couchdb
http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html

Execute:
add-cors-to-couchdb https://YOURDOMAIN.iriscouch.com:6984 -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

Result:
success

Check configuration again. Should show CORS enabled.
http: //YOURDOMAIN.iriscouch.com/_utils/config.html